# customised paging asp.net

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0

I want to implement customised paging where the pagenumbers are displayed like 
Prev 1 2 3 4 5...25 26 27 28 29 30 Next.

```
private void PopulatePager(int recordCount, int currentPage)
{
    double dblPageCount = (double)((decimal)recordCount / decimal.Parse(ddlPerPage.SelectedValue));
    int pageCount = (int)Math.Ceiling(dblPageCount);
    recdcnt = pageCount;
    List<ListItem> pages = new List<ListItem>();
    if (pageCount > 0)
    {
        ListItem lp = new ListItem("Previous", "1", currentPage > 1);
        lp.Attributes.Add("class", "pages previous");
        pages.Add(lp);
        //pages.Add(new ListItem("First", "1", currentPage > 1));
        for (int i = 1; i <= pageCount; i++)
        {
            // pages.Add(new ListItem(i.ToString(), i.ToString(), i != currentPage));
            ListItem li = new ListItem(i.ToString(), i.ToString(), i != currentPage);
            li.Attributes.Add("class", "pages");


            pages.Add(li);
        }
        ListItem ll = new ListItem("Next", pageCount.ToString(), currentPage < pageCount);
        ll.Attributes.Add("class", "pages next");
        pages.Add(ll);
        //pages.Add(new ListItem("Last", pageCount.ToString(), currentPage < pageCount));
    }
    rptPager.DataSource = pages;
    rptPager.DataBind();
}
```

rptPager is the repeater.

This displays the output as 
Prev 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 Next
 But i want it to be displayed as Prev 1 2 3 4 5...25 26 27 28 29 30 Next.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Write logic to show only previous 5 page number including current page and last 5 page numbers

```
  for (int i = 1; i <= pageCount; i++)
  {
      if ((i > currentPage - 5 && i <= currentPage) || (i > pageCount - 5))
      {
          // pages.Add(new ListItem(i.ToString(), i.ToString(), i != currentPage));
          ListItem li = new ListItem(i.ToString(), i.ToString(), i != currentPage);
          li.Attributes.Add("class", "pages");

          pages.Add(li);
      }
      else if (((ListItem)pages[pages.Count - 1]).Text != "...")
      {
          ListItem li = new ListItem("...",String.Empty);
          li.Attributes.Add("class", "pages");
          pages.Add(li);
      }
  }
```

Comment: I have tried implementing your logic but it is not working as expected. I want that on clicking of the 5 link the next 5 pages should be loaded and so on

Comment: then you must again call populate pager on page change event

Comment: I am getting the pages as expected but how to hide the previous pages as new pages gets added to the pages list

Comment: are you binding pager everytime page index changes, if yes when you call rptPager.DataSource = pages;rptPager.DataBind(); it should clear all the previous pages and bind new pages

Comment: I think you just have to call PopulatePager method from PageIndexChanged event.

Comment: Any suggestion or ideas please